# trim on String in Proccessing causes NullPointerException

Tags: arduino, port, processing, trim

I have a little problem with my Processing sketch. I am trying to get a value from my Arduino via Serial connection. In this case, it's an ultrasonic sensor, which should return the distance. In the Arduino Software Serial-Monitor, I have the right Values between 2 and 300. But after sending it to Processing, I only get ASCII Codes, which I want to convert to String. But the converted String then contains also line feed and carriage return - I don't want these.

I thought, I can erase this line feed and return carriage by using trim. But now I only get a `NullPointerException` in `trim(distance)`. I don't know what to do now.

My Arduino Sketch in the Ultrasonic Section:

```java
//Ultraschall
    int duration, distance
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    //Calculate the distance (in mm)
    distance = duration / 5.8;
    Serial.println(distance);
    delay(50);
```

My Processing Sketch in the Ultrasonic Section:

Above Setup:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
```

in Draw:

```java
  String distance = port.readString();
  String distanceTrim = trim(distance);
  println (distanceTrim);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show the full error please?

Comment: I got an `InvalidGrammarException` when reading your post. Please note that visual quality of your post has influence on the number of votes (both positive and negative) and answers you receive. You're ignoring even the basic rules. I don't see a reason to do that and risk getting a downvote.

Comment: `String distanceTrim = trim(distance);` is marked.
The error is only: `NullPointerException`

Comment: Without the `String distanceTrim = trim(distance);` i receive right values, but always with return and spaces, so i cant use it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your `distance` variable is `null`. Try printing out its value to check this:

```java
String distance = port.readString();
println(distance);
String distanceTrim = trim(distance);
println (distanceTrim);
```

Your call to `port.readString()` is returning `null`. I don't know exactly why that is, but the source of your `NullPointerException` is from passing `null` into the `trim()` function.